# Proposal for background illustration for art and crafts se Web page

Tags: discussion

If it is not a hard and fast rule that "a beta-branch can't use illustrations on top bars and backgrounds", there should be use of page-illustrations. Isn't?

In my preference a soft landscape or meadow or stream or such could be used.